# image augmentation of keras, how it works?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am reading [Fit generator and data augmentation in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789414/fit-generator-and-data-augmentation-in-keras), but there are still something that I am not quite sure about image augmentation in keras.

(1) In datagen.flow(), we also set a batch_size. I know batch_size is needed if we do mini-batch training, so are these two batch_size values the same, i mean, if we indicate batch_size in flow() generator, are we assuming we will do mini-batch training with the same batch_size?

(2)
Let me assume the size of training set is 10,000. I guess the only difference between model.fit_generator() and model.fit() at each epoch is that, for the former one, we are using 10,000 of randomly transformed images, rather than the original 10,000 ones. But for other epochs, we are using another 10,000 images which are totally different than those used in the first epoch, because all the images are randomly generated. Is it right?
It is like we are always using new images at each epoch, which is different from the ordinary case, when the same set of images are used at each epoch.

I am new to this area. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

the 1st question:the answer is YES.

the 2nd question:yes we are always using new images at each epoch,if we use data augmentation in model.fit_generator()